# Generic Binding in Ninject without a default constructor

Tags: generics, binding, ninject

Ninject seems to be having issues resolving the following:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class,IEntity
{
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class,IEntity
{
    protected IDbContext _context;

    public Repository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

When there is a need to do something special, I do:

```
public interface IMyEntityRepository : IRepository<MyEntity>
{
    int GetSomeStuffForAnObject();
}
```

That works great, but binding doesn't work if I am just using the default `Repository<T>`.

Comment: Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));

Comment: PLease use the _"edit"_ link under the tag line to edit your question and put in your commented code (I have no idea where to put)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I must have missed something earlier.

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

Seems to work.